# Entity Framework setting an entry to modified throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

While writing an update method for my Entity Framework repository, I include the following code:

```
public bool UpdateProduct(int id, Models.Product product)
{
    Product ctxProduct = GetProductIncludingProductLists(id); //Pulls directly from context
    if (ctxProduct != null && product != null)
    {
        /*Update ctxProduct fields using product*/

        _ctx.Entry(ctxProduct).State = EntityState.Modified; //_ctx is my DbContext
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the line of code where I set the entity's status to modified throws the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Attaching an entity of type '***.***.Product' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I am confused by what this error message is trying to tell me. Since I have pulled this entry out of the context, the only thing its Primary key should be conflicting with is itself.  In addition, I know this entry has been assigned an id since I accessed it using its id.

Lastly, the reason I am setting this entry's state to modified is because calling `_ctx.saveChanges()` is returning 0, indicating to me that the context isn't aware I've changed anything (when I have).

Can anyone explain why this error is being thrown and what I need to do to make the context aware of my changes?

EDIT

GetProductIncludingProductLists(id):

```
    public Product GetProductIncludingProductLists(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return _ctx.Products.Include("ProductLists")
                                    .ToList()
                                    .Select(p => new Product()
                                    {
                                        ProductId = p.ProductId,
                                        CUSIP = p.CUSIP,
                                        SEDOL = p.SEDOL,
                                        BUID = p.BUID,
                                        Key = p.Key,
                                        Track = p.Track,
                                        ProductLists = ((p.ProductLists.Select(l => new ProductList()
                                        {
                                            ProductListId = l.ProductListId,
                                            Name = l.Name,
                                            Products = null
                                        })
                                        .ToList() as List<ProductList>) ?? null)
                                    })
                                    .First(item => item.ProductId == id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The reason for the crazy select statements is because product and product list are related N:N and not including them would cause an error for 'circular serialization'

Comment: Can you include GetProductIncludingProductLists(id) please?

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward.  Entity Framework has a cache of entities you've retrieved from the database.  This entity has already been added to the local cache, so you can't add a non-attached entity to the cache because another version (one from the database most likely) is already in the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a *new* product that is not being change tracked by Entity Framework:

.Select(p => new Product()

Comment: So now how do I get rid of that without breaking the serialization?

Comment: Serialization is a different issue, and probably the issue you should be solving for.

Comment: Need more info, what are you trying to serialize?

Comment: If I didn't include the select statements the line of code `return _ctx.Products.Include("ProductLists").ToList();` would throw an error saying that circular dependencies were breaking the serialization - I'll try to get the error message

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to send the entity over the wire, probably via WCF. Here are two approaches I can think of, try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx or take the Entity and convert it to a DTO without circular dependency right before sending it over the wire.

Comment: Here's the response to a get call to the api: `{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":null,"innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Self referencing loop detected with type 'BPipeCustomRequester.Models.Product'. Path 'productLists[0].products'.","exceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"`

Comment: This should fix that error: http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into this and update when I'm done

Comment: The serialization is still being weird but I'm marking you as correct because you have answered this question.  I may post a new question about the serialization later.  Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 3):

looking at this code, I'm afraid there is some lack of knowledge on how EF works.

First, to load an entity this code is overcomplicated and does horrible things:

1: this loads all the products in the DB into memory

```
 return _ctx.Products.Include("ProductLists")
                                .ToList()
```

2: this copies the properties of already existing objects in new objects

```
.Select(p => new Product() {  // create new object and copy properties !!
```

3: this queries individually each of the related lists of each and every product in the DB (and creates a new list, when there is one already available)

```
p.ProductLists.Select( // query the list of each product !!
```

4: and all of this just to get a product with the given id!

```
.First(item => item.ProductId == id);
```

You can simply do this:

```
return _ctx.Products
   .Include(p => p.ProductLists)  // it's much safer a lambda than a magic string
   .First(item => item.ProductId == id);
```

which will load only the required product, with its corresponding product lists. And it will be attached to the context.

Second. If your product is already attached to the context, i.e. you've loaded it using the context, for example as I've just shown, and provided that `_ctx` has not been disposed, the product is already tracked by the context, and you don't need to care about setting its state. Whenever you make any change to it, the context will automatically change its state so that, when you call `SaveChanges` the changes will be automatically posted to the DB.

As you can see your code is overcomplicated. Try to make some tutorials to understand how EF works. You'll spare a lot of time. You can use the [EF section of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). It has clear documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

the first ToList() bring all products in the context (are you sure you want that ?).

then you create new one with the select

trying to attach the new one conflict with the loaded one.